# pandas dataframe (Selection)

Tags: python, pandas

easy pandas dataframe problem here.

I create dataframe by reading csv file, print it

```
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    Int64Index: 176 entries, 0 to 175
    Data columns (total 8 columns):
    ID            176  non-null values
    study         176  non-null values
    center        176  non-null values
    initials      176  non-null values
    age           147  non-null values
    sex           133  non-null values
    lesion age    35  non-null values
    group         35  non-null values
    dtypes: float64(2), int64(1), object(5)
```

why this give me an error when I try to select row from dataframe according to certain 
conditions

```
SUBJECTS[SUBJECTS.study=='NO2' and SUBJECTS.center=='Hermann']
```

Error Information:

```
    ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
SUBJECTS[(SUBJECTS.study=='NO2') & (SUBJECTS.center=='Hermann')]
```

---

The `and` causes Python to evaluate `SUBJECTS.study=='NO2'` and 
`SUBJECTS.center=='Hermann')` in boolean context (either `True` or `False`.)

In your case, you don't want either evaluated as booleans. Instead, you want element-wise logical `and`. This is specified by `&` instead of `and`.

---

The error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

is raised whenever you try to evaluate a NumPy array or Pandas NDFrame in a boolean context. Consider

```
bool(np.array([True, False]))
```

some users might expect this to return `True` since the array is *non-empty*. Or some might expect `True` since *at least one* element of the array is `True`. Others might expect it to return `False` since not *all* elements in the array are `True`. Since there are multiple, equally valid expectations for what a boolean context should return, the designers of NumPy and Pandas have decided to force users to be explicit: Use `.all()` or `.any()` or `len()`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. The error is due to how `numpy` functions under the hood of `pandas`, considering these examples:

```
In [158]:
a=np.array([1,2,1,1,1,1,2])
b=np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,1])

In [159]:
#Array Boolean operation
a==1
Out[159]:
array([ True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [160]:
#Array Boolean operation
b==1
Out[160]:
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [161]:
#and is not an array Boolean operation
(a==1) and (b==1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-161-271ddf20f621> in <module>()
----> 1 (a==1) and (b==1)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

In [162]:
#But & operates on arrays 
(a==1) & (b==1)
Out[162]:
array([ True, False,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [163]:
#Or *
(a==1) * (b==1)
Out[163]:
array([ True, False,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [164]:
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b})
In [166]:
#Therefore this is a good approach
df[(df.a==1) & (df.b==1)]
Out[166]:
a   b
0    1   1
2    1   1
2 rows × 2 columns

In [167]:
#This will also get you there, but it is not preferred.
df[df.a==1][df.b==1]
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:1686: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  "DataFrame index.", UserWarning)
Out[167]:
a   b
0    1   1
2    1   1
2 rows × 2 columns
```

Comment: Thank you very much Zhu CT, I have read all your codes and it helps my  understanding a lot :) @CT Zhu